# Probability : 2 matrix with N^2 numbers each.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Squared sudoku matrix in order of n, is a matrix nXn whose cells contain all integers between 1 to n^2.

[Example for order of 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2gJxW.png)

We'll draw two squares of sudoku in order of n by arranging the numbers in a square randomly. The draw between the two squares is independent.

What is the probability that all numbers are in the same row in both squares?

for example:
[image]

Thanks for the help.

[

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! Please, don't use images as main content of your post. This makes your question impossible to search and inaccessible to the visually impaired. Please transcribe text and mathematics (note that you can [use LaTeX](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/)) and don't forget to give proper attribution to your sources. A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are some helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960).

Comment: Your example has numbers $1$ to $16$, not four copies of $1$ to $4$.  It is misleading to call it sudoku.  It is just a matrix with those numbers in it.  Are there any restrictions on where the numbers are placed?

Comment: for my example I wrote the order is 4 (n=4 ) and not 1 to 16. You are right about the sudoku ill change it to matrix. 
And no more restriction than what in the above: the numbers should be the same in the same row and they go from 1 to n^2 for each matrix.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the first square is fixed. The conditional probability (given the first square) is
$$\frac{\text{number of ways the second square can satisfy the condition}}{\text{total number of possibilities for the second squares}} = \frac{(4!)^4}{16!}$$
(If you know which numbers must go in the first row, then there are $4!$ ways to arrange them in that row. Same goes for the other three rows.)

Now argue that this is also the unconditional probability, since each possible first square is equally likely.